# Javascript retrieve vertical columns winner

Tags: javascript

I have games named Columns where you can bet  on which one of the 10 vertical columns of the 80-number matrix will gather the most of the 20 drawn numbers. 
There is no Draw. in case of draw columns the winning columns is the one whose numbers where drawn first.

i need an algorithm to calculate which columns win based on a  drawn numbers

Example

```
80 Matrix 
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9    Col10
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80


First Extract number = [22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,21]
the winner is Col2

Second Extract number = [1,12,23,31,15,42,16,27,18,39,43,71,25,56,35,55,57,58,65,17]
The Winner is Col5
```

i have used the below code

```
number = [22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,21]

Matrix3 = [ {"Col":0,"selNum":0,"weight":0},
            {"Col":1,"selNum":0,"weight":0},
            {"Col":2,"selNum":0,"weight":0},
            {"Col":3,"selNum":0,"weight":0},
            {"Col":4,"selNum":0,"weight":0},
            {"Col":5,"selNum":0,"weight":0},
            {"Col":6,"selNum":0,"weight":0},
            {"Col":7,"selNum":0,"weight":0},
            {"Col":8,"selNum":0,"weight":0},
            {"Col":9,"selNum":0,"weight":0}
    ];


for (i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        Matrix3[((number[i]).toString()).slice(-1)].selNum = Matrix3[((number[i]).toString()).slice(-1)].selNum +1;
        Matrix3[((number[i]).toString()).slice(-1)].weight = Matrix3[((number[i]).toString()).slice(-1)].weight +i;


    }


console.log(Matrix3);
```

Now from the Matrix3 i need to check :

- if there are not duplicate on selNum return the Col with max selNum
- if there are duplicate with the same Max selNum return the Col , from the duplicate with the lower weight

Comment: You should add to your question what you have tried so far.

Comment: Added on my request the code that i try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes care of it by tracking the winner as the column entries are tallied in order (see the in-code comments for details):

```js
const nums = [22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,21];
const cols = nums.map( (num) => [num % 10]); // takes the last digit
let counts = {}, max = 0, winner = 0;

for (let col of cols){
  counts[col] = counts[col] ? counts[col] + 1 : 1; // adds 1 to the count for this column
  if(counts[col] > max){ // we have found a new maximum
    max = counts[col];
    winner = col > 0 ? col : 10; // updates winner (uses 10 if last digit is 0)
  }
}
console.log(winner);
```

Comment: Thank you that's was exactly was i needed

Answer (score 0):

If your Matrix has numbers structure like `1, 2, 3, 4, ...`, you can use **[remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())** to know in which column value is representing. See code below. Hope this helps.

```js
const COLUMNS_AMOUNT = 10

const getWinnerCol = (numbers) => {
  const columnsHits = new Array(COLUMNS_AMOUNT).fill(0)
  
  for (const number of numbers) {
    const columnHit = (number % COLUMNS_AMOUNT) || COLUMNS_AMOUNT
    
    columnsHits[columnHit - 1] += 1
  }
  
  console.log('columnsHits', columnsHits)
  
  return columnsHits.indexOf(Math.max(...columnsHits))
}

const firstNumbers = [22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,21],
      secondNumbers = [1,12,23,31,15,42,16,27,18,39,43,71,25,56,35,55,57,58,65,17]

console.log('Winner column index:', getWinnerCol(firstNumbers))
console.log('Winner column index:', getWinnerCol(secondNumbers))
```

Comment: sorry but for firstNumbers  i'm watiing 2

Comment: sorry but for firstNumbers i'm watiing 2 but i take 0 this because there duplicate .  in case of draw columns the winning columns is the one whose numbers where drawn first.

Comment: @MarcoRossi It's because every number in `firstNumbers` appears in each columns two times. `getWinnerCol ` function simply returns first column as winner.

Comment: you are correct the first column in which are select two number are the col2. the solution work only if there are not duplicate